# Bind controllers dynamicaly via ng-controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I wish to use the bootstrap.ui tabset with an array of tab-settings. These tab-setings include a name of the controller used to handle its contents. That way my 'tab-control' template stays light and clean.

```html
<div tabset>
    <div ng-repeat="tab in tabs"
         tab
         active="tab.isActive">
        <span tab-heading>{{ tab.title }}</span>
        <span ng-inlcude="tab.templateUrl" ng-controller="tab.controller"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

(note: the ng-include attribute i have not yet used in my code yet, was first testing the ng-controller.)

First i tried to us the controllers name... but ng-controller did not like that and refused to function as intended.

Then i tried to translate the name to a controller via the next snippet.

```js
for (var tabIdx = 0; tabIdx < tabs.length; tabIdx++) {
    var tab = tabs[tabIdx];

    if (typeof tab.controllerName == 'string') {
        var childScope = tab.scope = tab.scope || $scope.$new();

        childScope.someValue = 'I am created as [' + tab.controllerName + '] requested.';

        tab.controller = $controller(tab.controllerName, { $scope: childScope });
    }
}
```

But angular kindly informs me that a `function` was expected but it got a `controller` (you'd think `ng-controller` wouldn't mind getting a contoller).

So i changed the `$controller` call to:

```
tab.controller = $controller(tab.contollerName, { $scope: childScope }).constructor;
```

While this does work, kind of... my scope is not the scope i would like.

After this i thought of providing another function to the ng-contoller:

```
tab.controller = $controller.bind(null, tab.contollerName, { $scope: childScope });
```

But then the ng-controller could not find the $injectables.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Is missspelling of `ng-include` real ?

Comment: That is something we call in the Netherlands 'fat fingers'. Just a typo typing this code in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a directive for this, to assign the controller dynamically.

```
app.directive('tabCtrl', function ($controller) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      return $controller($scope.tab.controller, {
        $scope:   $scope,
        $element: $element,
        $attrs:   $attrs
      });
    }
  };
});
```

---

```
<span ng-inlcude="tab.templateUrl" tab-controller="tab.controller"></span>
```

---

**[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jojijanipa/1/edit?html,js,output)**

---

If you wanted to, you could take this a step further and do something along these lines:

```
app.directive('tab', function ($controller) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<ng-include src="tab.template"></ng-include>',
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      return $controller($scope.tab.controller, {
        $scope:   $scope,
        $element: $element,
        $attrs:   $attrs
      });
    }
  };
});
```

[jsBin for the extended version](http://jsbin.com/pojufipaja/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: After a deeper dive into angulars $controller i discovered the 3rd parameter 'later', a boolean indicating that the return value should not be a controller object but a function that will create the controller when called. Using this will make the 'ng-controller' version working. But the supplied `{ #scope: $scope.$new() }`does not get feed into my controller...

Comment: How come you want to feed the controller a `$new` $scope? isn't the $scope supplied by `ng-include` sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply specify the controller to use in the template:

Controller:

```
app.controller('rootCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.tabs = [
    { id: 1, name: 'tab1', template: 'template1.html' },
    { id: 2, name: 'tab2', template: 'template2.html' }
  ]
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="tab in tabs track by tab.id">
    <label class="tab">{{tab.name}}</label>
    <div ng-include="tab.template"></div>
 </div>
```

and in the template:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl1">
  ...
</div>
```

see the sample plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/vkmBhP8cr8DpiHwbs2Rd?p=preview

Comment: This does work but this way the controller is hardcoded and not part of my data. But could be workable.